How to dynamically add click handler to Ember Octane component - dynamic "on" modifier
I have a situation where I need to make a component and it has some logic to either render as a button or as a DIV depending on if it has a link.
{{#let
  (if
    this.hasLink
    (component "external-library-button$special-button")
    (element "div")
  )
  as |MaybeAButton|
}}
    <MaybeAButton
      {{on "click" this.onClick}} // can this be dynamically added?
    >
      ...lots of nested code
    </MaybeAButton>
{{/let}}

I tried to do add it dynamically but I get an error that "on" is not in scope.
{{(if this.hasLink (modifier on "click" this.onClick))}}

What's a good way to dynamically add a click handler?
I'd like to not add a listener if it won't be interactive.

If you're using ember-source@3.28+, you can conditionally apply the modifier using the modifier helper.
it would look like this
<a {{ (if this.hasLink (modifier on "click" this.onClick) ) }}>
  ...
</a>

You could also use a let, if you want to make reading the modifier a bit more focused
{{#let (modifier on "click" this.onClick) as |handleClick|}}
  <a {{ (if this.hasLink handleClick) }}>
    ...
  </a>
{{/let}}

NOTE: at the time of writing, I do not recall if it's on or 'on' -- may depend on the type of file you're in (loose mode or strict mode)

Thanks, I thought this would work but when using on I get Error: Attempted to resolve a value in a strict mode template, but that value was not in scope: on but when using 'on' I get Attempted to invoke (-resolve "modifier:on"), but on was not a valid modifier name. def an odd experience. Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/19869 which it looks like you commented the workaround for.

in strict mode, you need to import { on } from '@ember/modifier'

ah ok, I see what sort of situation you're in now -- yeah, the GH issue you link is still 100% valid

I'm settling on this as a temporary solution but I'm not sure I really want it. It still creates the listener which I don't like.
{{on "click" (if this. hasLink this. onClick null)}}

